# Why am I getting an incorrect payment total via Stripe in Python?

Tags: python, stripe-payments

I'm trying to make a payment through the ecommerce website I created. The payment successfully went through but the total amount charged is different than what I wanted to charge. For example, I want to charge $29.19 but I get charged $2,918.90. I know it has something to do with the decimal places, but I seem to have it correct; 2 decimal places.

I tried adding decimal to the subtotal, tax, and shipping to get a decimal total, though it came, I still had a wrong total amount.

My cart.py:

```
def get_total(self):
        
        subtotal = sum(Decimal(item['price']) * int(item['quantity']) for item in self.cart.values())
        tax = Decimal('0.10')
        tax_price = sum(Decimal(item['price']) * int(item['quantity']) for item in self.cart.values()) * Decimal(tax)

        shipping_cost = 5
        total = Decimal(subtotal) + Decimal(tax_price) + Decimal(shipping_cost)
        return total
```

My Payment views.py:

```
@login_required
def CartView(request):
    cart = Cart(request)
    total = str(cart.get_total())
    total = total.replace('.', '')

    stripe.api_key = ''
    intent = stripe.PaymentIntent.create(
        amount=total,
        currency='usd',
        metadata={'userid': request.user.id}
    )
```

Order class:

```
total_paid = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

OrderItem class:

```
price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=5, decimal_places=2)
```

Comment: The amount is supposed to be a positive integer.  Perhaps it does different processing for strings.  If you do `int(total)`, does that fix it?  For example, `total = int(cart.get_total() * 100)`?

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the PaymentIntent object in the Stripe documentation you can see that the `amount` parameter accepts the price in the smallest currency unit.

> Amount intended to be collected by this PaymentIntent. A positive
> integer representing how much to charge in the smallest currency unit
> (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100, a zero-decimal
> currency).

If you want to charge $1.00 the amount you pass to the PaymentIntent should be 100. If you want to charge $29.19 the amount you pass should be 2919.

Instead of  `total = total.replace('.', '')` try making a int amount and multiply it by a 100 (or store the prices in the cents beforehand).

Comment: It turns out that I was supposed to do something like this: total = int(float(total) * 100) Thanks for the help of pointing me in the right direction!